# How to capture response.code for each url that is attempted to scrape?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I have a large list of URLs to scrape and after multiple tests, I noticed that in the output from the execution of the spider there are a results sections that show all the response codes that the crawler encountered. But when I run my code that has this simple line in it, ALL the urls come back with a Code = 200

```
urlStatusCode = response.status
```

In the debug window the break down is like this and was hoping to capture the same thing in my file so that I can easily identify which URLs I need to go validate and adjust the code if needed.

```
Response Count 200 = 2494
Response Count 301 = 122
Response Count 404 = 37
```

I know what they all mean, but I would like to capture these actual codes in my CSV file that is creating with the scrape so that I can investigate the troubled URLS.

Comment: Can you share your code, and expected output in CSV?

Comment: See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-errbacks-to-catch-exceptions-in-request-processing

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you want to capture `301` response codes. When Scrapy find a `301`, by default it yields a new request for the redirect target (a new URL), and your callback only receives the response to the final URL (after following all redirects).

As for `404` responses, they never reach your callback by default. If you want your callback to receive these responses, you have two options:

- Add `404` to the [`HTTP_ALLOWED_CODES`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html?#std:setting-HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES) setting, so that `404` responses also reach your callbacks
- [Use an errback](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-errbacks-to-catch-exceptions-in-request-processing) to handle `404` responses

Comment: i will get to handling them as i continue to build and make things more efficient. But during this debugging and building i just need to know which URLS are receiving the 404 so i can go validate and make sure and if they truely dont exist then i can just remove them from my list and build the error handling.. but i will review the above suggestions..

Comment: You can also check the logs. They do indicate which URLs resulted in which error code. You could redirect the log output to a file and then check the file contents to find the 404 URLs.